# How to create these webpages

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm a beginner in coding. I'm having an issue on how to go about creating this component of my web project: I'm trying to make a review website sort of like yelp. The user clicks on a link about subject A and will see a list of reviews about subject A. And so on if the user clicks on a link for subject B, C, D etc. 
However, I don't want to create individual php pages for each link for each subject
example of what I'm talking about:

```
<a href="subjectA.php">subjectA</a>
<a href="subjectB.php">subjectB</a>
```

and so on, because then I would end up with like 20 php files (I have a lot of subjects that the user can review on). Each subject has the same css and page format but different content. Whats a much better and practical solution to this because I know my way is not the best. For this project I can only use html,php and js.

Thanks.

Comment: It seems that keywords "php single page application" would find good results for your task to start with. Changing php to javascript or HTML gives you even more useful results ...

Answer (score 0):

Since it's just a project. I won't go too much into detail but would give you a simple idea:

You can do something like this:

```
# Home.php
<a href="checkOutReviews.php?subject=1">Subject One</a>
<a href="checkOutReviews.php?subject=2">Subject Two</a>
....
....
```

And then,

```
# checkOutReviews.php
$subject_id = $_GET['subject'];
/** Get subject details from the database or any other storage of your choice **/
/** and just display them **/
```

This way you won't have to create pages for each of your subjects.

Comment: `checkOutReviews.php/?subject=1` that slash probably doesn't belong there

Answer (score -1):

You need to have 2 web pages in the same directory, **subjectA.php** and **subjectB.php**

To create a php page you can use any text editor but you must have apache server install and running to run php file.

```
<?php
//your code goes here..
?>
```

Comment: What OP needs, can be achieved with a single page.

Comment: You need to make html page instead of php

Comment: Why is that? It won't make any difference how the requested HTML is produced on a server.

Comment: Have you read the question? Two/many pages is not what OP wants, he wants to use one page only. "_you must have apache server install_" Apache alone won't serve PHP files. What about Nginx?